# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor when processing large number of requests [Uvicorn/FastAPI]

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm using python 3.9 and in a uvicorn fastAPI script.

Sometimes when I'm processing a large number of items, I get this error and the whole script gets killed, It's a bunch of aiohttp requests

```
Getting Metadata Accounts: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10000/10000 [02:04<00:00, 80.28it/s]
Got Metadata for 10000 NFTs
Parsing Arweaves
Parsing Arweaves:   2%|█▌                                                                                                   | 152/10000 [01:27<1:53:22,  1.45it/s]Exception in callback UVTransport._call_connection_made
handle: <Handle UVTransport._call_connection_made>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uvloop/cbhandles.pyx", line 66, in uvloop.loop.Handle._run
  File "uvloop/handles/tcp.pyx", line 155, in uvloop.loop.TCPTransport._call_connection_made
  File "uvloop/handles/basetransport.pyx", line 145, in uvloop.loop.UVBaseTransport._call_connection_made
  File "uvloop/handles/basetransport.pyx", line 142, in uvloop.loop.UVBaseTransport._call_connection_made
  File "/home/bewinxed/Downloads/GuardianGeckoBot/nifty/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/base_protocol.py", line 58, in connection_made
    tcp_nodelay(tr, True)
  File "/home/bewinxed/Downloads/GuardianGeckoBot/nifty/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/tcp_helpers.py", line 26, in tcp_nodelay
    sock = transport.get_extra_info("socket")
  File "uvloop/handles/tcp.pyx", line 166, in uvloop.loop.TCPTransport.get_extra_info
  File "uvloop/handles/basetransport.pyx", line 285, in uvloop.loop.UVBaseTransport.get_extra_info
  File "uvloop/handles/handle.pyx", line 249, in uvloop.loop.UVSocketHandle._get_socket
  File "uvloop/handles/tcp.pyx", line 169, in uvloop.loop.TCPTransport._new_socket
  File "uvloop/handles/tcp.pyx", line 50, in uvloop.loop.__tcp_get_socket
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

What could be the issue? I google and all I see is talk about Sockets but I'm not using it explicitly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like this issue: https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop/issues/414 . Can you apply the patch `graingert` suggested in the thread?